# What could be the reason behind the variation in coil size inside Apple's Magic Trackpad 2 haptic motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux, apple, haptics

**Disclaimer: This is a speculative question looking for electromagnetic coil advice, using Apple construction decisions as the talking point.

Looking through [iFixit's teardown of the Apple Magic Trackpad 2](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Magic+Trackpad+2+Teardown/51032) I came across this picture showing the construction of the module that creates the vibration (replicating a click feeling if you're unfamiliar). It's function is simple - use electromagnetism to push and pull the steel bar mounter to the top plate to create vibration.

I don't know the exact waveform that Apple is implementing to replicate the click feeling, but I'd imagine all the coils are wired to work together pushing and pulling the bar backwards and forwards once or twice.

[image]

**I'd love to hear any possible reasons for designing the module to have 2 smaller coils? What can the smaller coils do that the middle bigger 2 cannot?**

Why would they not have opted for 3 of the same size coils? Or even 1 big one? My first and only thought is derived from an audio monitor tweeter, being that smaller coils are able to produce higher frequencies more effectively, but I feel as though the size difference is not big enough for that to make sense (and tweeters have a different cone design, and aren't just attached to the main cone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below.  The coil winding direction is reversed on each coil, so the magnetic flux path (blue arrows) has a short, closed path through the steel (except for the gap).

[image]

Comment: There you go, thanks so much for this! One more question: since the steel plays a role in completing the magnetic path, can it still be attracted/repelled by the fields generated?

Comment: When the coil is energized with current flowing in either direction, the black and silver pieces have an attractive force.  If the materials is magnetically "soft,"  this force will be gone when the field is removed.  The steel may have a small amount of remanence, meaning that it can remain slightly magnetized after it is exposed to an external field. 
 If so, when if the field is reversed, there may be a short period of repulsion before it is again attracted.  But the repelling force will be small and short-lived.